# What are the best places near Kennedy Space Center to watch a night launch?

Tags: nasa

Will the below official launch viewing areas be open for a night launch (Atlas V at 7:40 p.m. on 18 Jan 2018)? If not, what are the other options?
THE LC-39 OBSERVATION GANTRY
APOLLO/SATURN V CENTER
NASA CAUSEWAY
MAIN VISITOR COMPLEX

Comment: Would it not be better to ask [Kennedy Space Center](https://www.kennedyspacecenter.com/) directly ?

Comment: This question may find a quicker answer at Space Exploration Stackexchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about astronomy.

Comment: I suggest to re-ask this on https://space.stackexchange.com .